# podman container with public IPv6

Tags: ipv6, podman

I have got a server with IPv4 address and IPv6 /64 subnet (let's say `2001:db8::/64`), both public. Server itself has the following IPv6 address: `2001:db8::1/64`. The gateway is `fe80::1` (which causes problems with podman, because it's not in the same subnet).

My goal is to create podman container (WWW server, for example) with its own public IPv6 (let's say `2001:db8::2/64`). From my understanding, such a setup needs macvlan network. So the setup would look as follows:

[image: picture1]

I managed to partially fulfill this setup using bridge network and the following command:
`sudo podman network create --subnet 2001:db8::/64 --ipv6 mynet`
Container within this network was accessiable from Internet via correct IP (`2001:db8::2`), but its public IP (for http, ping etc.) was wrong - it was `2001:db8::1`, which is totally understandable when using bridge network.

Things get complicated when I tried using macvlan, first problem was the gateway which needs to be set to `fe80::1`. `docker` refused to create such network with error "no matching subnet for gateway fe80::1". `podman` successfully create network using the following command:
`sudo podman network create -d macvlan --subnet 2001:db8::/64 --gateway fe80::1 --ipv6 -o parent=eth0 mynet`
Unfortunately, a container inside this network has no connectivity in any direction, even though it has correct IP and gateway specified.

Server is working on Ubuntu, with enabled IP routing in kernel.

Any ideas how this setup could be made would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [..which causes problems with docker/podman, because it's not in the same subnet] – It doesn't have to be in the _same_ subnet as long as it's in _any_ of your subnets (and every host is in the fe80::/64 subnet), so docker/podman ought to accept it.  [..which is totally understandable when using bridge network] – That actually sounds _not like a bridge network at all_ to me. I don't know what a "bridge" means in Docker world, but that's not how normal bridges work; they are not supposed to NAT IP packets.

Comment: Anyway: 1) Could your network provider assign you a routed prefix, e.g. a /56 routed to your host? 2) Do Docker&podman require a /64, or could you set up a container network with a longer prefix (e.g. a /96)? Instead of macvlans, Proxy-NDP using ndpresponder could make that work in general, but I don't know where to start with container tools.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It seems that prefix size was a key. I have been using /64, but when I changed to longer ones like /112 everything started working. Furthermore, I didn't need to use macvlan, just simple bridge.

Comment: Using network sizes other than `/64` can cause problems with IPv6. Yes, you should just bridge because all the devices are on the same network.